# Adding ChromeOptions for Selenium Webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium

From what I understand, the default action of when the Webdriver finds an element is to scroll such that the element is as far up the top of the page as possible. This is an issue because the website I'm working on has a header so every time I try to click on a button, it will instead click on the header. Thus, I want to change the scroll setting so that the element will be at the bottom of the page.

From reading [this](https://help.crossbrowsertesting.com/selenium-testing/getting-started/crossbrowsertesting-automation-capabilities/) I was able to find what I wanted to set, however, I'm unable to set the DesiredCapabilites or ChromeOptions when I initialise the ChromeDriver. Could some provide code/steps to do this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", "en");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");

var driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

**Edit-2**
If the option you want to set doesn't work for you then try using actions

```
var elem = driver.FindElements(By.Id("your element"));
Actions action  = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(elem).Click(elem).Perform();//move to list element that needs to be hovered
```

**Edit-3**

If the above also doesn't work then your next option is to use Javascript

```
var elem = driver.FindElements(By.Id("your element"));

IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var success = js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click(); return true", elem);
```

Comment: Thank you for this but this doesn't set the default scrolling to be at the bottom

Comment: I tried 'elementScrollBehaviour' but it doesn't work as expected

Comment: I originally tried using actions but they don't seem to work for me either :/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't change everything through addarguments.
There is a list of what you can do in the Github page. but I have a better solution. you can make your own default settings and save it as a chrome profile. for example I didn't find anything to change homepage with code but this works fine for almost evwerything.

you can use this code :

> options.AddArguments( @"user-data -dir=C:\Users\kian\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data");
> options.AddArgument("--profile-directory=Default");

make sure you write the right path and right profile name.
to check the profile name you can go to properties.
[properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rNGW.png)

you will see the profile name.

there is a good guide for what else u can do in [link](https://www.agilequalitymadeeasy.com/post/selenium-c-tutorial-chrome-options-concepts-to-simplifying-web-testing).